# Aurora Serverless Blue/Green deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, mysql-replication, amazon-rds

I am currently investigating strategies for implementing blue/green deployment using RDS Aurora Serverless for Mysql.

The 2 methods I am thinking about are:

**A.** Create a duplicate database and migrate the duplicate to the new schema. Basically, I would maintain two versions of the DB until the deployment is complete, then delete the original.

**B.** Always keep the same database, and more or less support two schemas at the same time. This means I would be doing things like keeping duplicate columns if I wanted to change a column name, so my old queries would continue to function for both the old and new versions of my app.

I have a few questions about the feasibility of both of these:

1. For method **A**, is there a reasonable way to duplicate a database using Aurora Serverless? My understanding is that snapshots cannot be used to create a duplicate DB.
2. For method **A**, what options exist for keeping both databases in sync. (I was thinking using Kinesis might work)
3. For method **B**, what options exist for keeping duplicate columns/tables in sync. It would be fairly simple to just update both columns for users on the new version of the API, but I'm not sure how to deal with the old version of the API not knowing the new column exists.

I am also open to suggestions about different strategies.

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating a database copy** for every deployment (*Method A*) is quite a **complicated approach**.

It only works when your database is: *fairly small* (copying takes time, keeping 2 large DBs [blue and green] costs 2x the money, etc), *fairly static* with few writes (keeping the two in sync can be a challenge for busy DBs) and when you *don't expect to roll back* (back-porting updates from a *busy new green DB* back to the *old blue DB* may be complicated).

It can be done but it's complicated. Tools like *[AWS Database Migration Service (DMS)](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)* that can do both the initial copy and subsequently keep the DBS in sync can help with some of it.

---

**Using the same DB for both blue and green** (your *Method B*) is **usually preferred** and much easier to work with. Also in reality most of the time database fields are *added* between code releases, less often they are *deleted* or *renamed*. But even that can be done.

Say you want to rename a `username` field to `user_name` for whatever reason, e.g. to bring it in line with new naming conventions. Here is what you can do:

1. *Code version 1* expects `username` and the database schema has `username` field.
2. Add column `user_name` with default `NULL`
3. Deploy *code version 2* - it tries to authenticate against `user_name` and if it finds that `user_name` is `NULL` it falls back to `username` and updates `user_name`. If a new user is created it's saved to `user_name` and in a separate step to `username`.

   If accessing the old `username` column fails because it's no longer an existing column that's ok.
4. Once *version 2* is fully deployed and tested run a script that updates all remaining `user_name` rows from `username`.
5. Deploy *version 3* that only works with `user_name`.
6. Once *version 3* is deployed remove the old column `username` because both current (v3) and previous (v2) can work without.

This may look complicated but it's not that bad.

**This approach has a number of advantages:**

- it's only *software engineering problem*, your CI/CD pipeline doesn't have to support copying and syncing databases and rolling them back.
- most often between software releases the database doesn't change and if it does it usually only *adds new columns*, which is trivial and backwards compatible.
- you can use the same approach if you decide to use *rolling deployment* or *canary deployment* instead of *blue/green* in the future.

Hope that helps :)